# Update the VPN for all VPN users in specific security group and laptop OU

Tags: windows, powershell

I am wondering if this is even possible to be done. I need to update at login the VPN settings of all Security group VPN users who are signing on via their laptop in the approved laptop OU. I am concerned if this is even possible since the update would have to occur after login and the remove the old VPN settings at logoff so they only have the one VPN setting for access to work.

I haven't been able to get both the security group and OU so wondering how to do this.

Comment: Start with [ActiveDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/?view=win10-ps) Module

Comment: This is what I have so far, haven't tested yet, but the Get.ADGroupMember seems to be the way to do this.

WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

If (identity.name = Get.ADGroupMember -Identity "VPN*" then